# Toastr is behaving strangely with query

Tags: jquery, laravel-8, toastr

I am using Toastr messages on a laravel project together with jquery to present information for the user. But if I need to persist the toast and let user click on the button I noticed that toast doesn't work as expected.

For example the close button is present, but is not working and also when the user hovers over the toast it's not responding and from transparent to become solid. Below is how the message appears regardless if it's hovered or not.

[image]

On top of all those the toast doesn't react on any click event and I can click the link below the toast message as if the toast was not present.

The code that I have used or the above toastr is:

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": 0,
  "extendedTimeOut": 0,
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
  "tapToDismiss": true
};
toastr.success(res.message);
```

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Check the browser console to ensure that no javascript errors are happening.

Comment: No errors are reported on the console!